# Fill a range of cells based on another cell but continue the numerical series of numbers 7,8,9...

Tags: vba, excel

This is the code that I'm currently using. But I want it to take the numerical value that it's grabbing from A2 and increase it by 1 as it fills in the range of ColN. This would create a series of numbers instead of all being the same number.

```
Order = Range("A2")

Range("N2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Order
Range("N2").Select
Range("N2", Range("N2").End(xlDown)).Name = "typeColRange"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("N2:N" & Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just do a good ol' for loop? Sometimes simple is best and more importantly, it's easier to tell what the code is trying to do when you look at it.

```
Sub test()

Dim i As Long, lastCell As Long, counter As Long

lastCell = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
counter = Range("A2").Value

For i = 2 To lastCell
    Cells(i, "N") = counter
    counter = counter + 1
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You can also turn off screen-updating, but a simple for loop should be pretty instant anyway, so I don't think it matters either way.